# Basic LISP recursive replacement of substring

Tags: replace, lisp, common-lisp

I'm trying to replace any occurrences of a given string in a list with "X", using basic LISP commands (e.g. no `mapcar`) in a recursive function.

```
(defun removetext (symbol list replaced)
    (if (not list)   ; if initial list has been exhausted, return replaced list
        replaced
        (progn
            (if (eql (car list) symbol)   ; otherwise, if first element of list = symbol, replace with "X"
                (removetext symbol (cdr list) (cons "X" replaced)) 
                (removetext symbol (cdr list) (cons (car list) replaced)) ; otherwise keep it 
            )
            (format t "~D" replaced)
        )
    )
)
```

This does not work if I call it with `(removetext "E" '(A B C D E F F E) "")`.

This returns `NIL` and the printout looks like `(F F E D C B A . )(F E D C B A . )(E D C B A . )(D C B A . )(C B A . )(B A . )(A . )`.

I want it to return `(A B C D X F F X)`.

Comment: Note that `"E"` is a character string, whereas `E` is as symbol. These are different data types. If we compare them with `eql`, the comparison will always be false.  Moreover, two strings cannot be reliably compared with `eql`; that only tests whether they are actually the same object, not whether they are equivalent strings; we need `equal`.  Symbols have a name, and that name is a character string. Thus `(symbol-name 'e)` returns the string `"E"`. Thus `(equal (symbol-name 'e) "E")` yields true. We can also compare a string to a symbol directly using `string=`: `(string= "E" 'e)` yields true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(defun removetext (symbol list replaced)
  (if (null list)
      (reverse replaced)
    (if (eql (car list) symbol)
        (removetext symbol (cdr list) (cons 'x         replaced)) 
        (removetext symbol (cdr list) (cons (car list) replaced)))))
```

Example:

```
CL-USER > (removetext 'E '(A B C D E F F E) ())
(A B C D X F F X)
```

Answer (score 2):

None of the other answers so far have addressed an important problem in your code.  Given this slightly different but structurally similar version of your function:

```
(defun replace-thing (list thing by &key (test #'eql))
  (labels ((replace-it (tail replaced)
             (if (null tail)
                 (reverse replaced)
               (progn
                 (if (funcall test (first tail) thing)
                     (replace-it (rest tail) (cons by replaced)) 
                   (replace-it (rest tail) (cons (first tail) replaced)))
                 (format t "~&got ~S~%" replaced)))))
    (replace-it list '())))
```

This will fail in the same way as one of the ways yours does:

```
 > (replace-thing '(a b c) 'a 'c)
 (b c)
 (c)
 nil
nil
```

And the reason it's failing is because what `progn` does.  You've written

```
(progn
  ... compute the thing you care about ...
  (format ...))
```

And the value(s) of `progn` are the value(s) of the *last* form in its body, so in this case the value of `(format ...)` which is `nil`.

There are two solutions to this: one that works for you and one that is more general.

The solution that works for you is to realise that `replaced` is never altered (your function does no mutation, which is good), so you can safely print it *first*:

```
(progn
  (format t "~& ~S~%" replaced)
  (if (funcall test (first tail) thing)
      (replace-it (rest tail) (cons by replaced)) 
    (replace-it (rest tail) (cons (first tail) replaced))))
```

This change will make my function work.

A more general solution is to realise that what you want is some form, say `first-thing` which, when used as

```
(first-thing
  thing1
  ...
  thingn)
```

Will:

1. do the things in its body in order;
2. then return the value(s) of the *first* of them.

Well, you can write such a form pretty easily as a macro.  Here's a slightly restricted version:

```
(defmacro first-thing (thing1 &body more-things)
  (let ((sn (make-symbol "STASH")))
    `(let ((,sn ,thing1))
       ,@more-things
       ,sn)))
```

Then

```
> (first-thing 1 (print "hi") (print "there"))

"hi" 
"there" 
1
```

But in fact you don't need to do that: CL offers both this restricted one and a more general one:

- the restricted one is `prog1` – `(prog1 thing1 ... thingn)` evaluates the things in order and then returns the first value of the first thing;
- the general one is `multiple-value-prog1` – `(multiple-value-prog1 thing1 ... thingn)` evaluates the things in order and then returns *all* the values of the first one.

`multiple-value-prog1` is almost certainly more expensive than `prog1` since it needs to stash multiple values somewhere and hence almost certainly conses.  In your case you only need `prog1` though, so a version of (my version of) your function is:

```
(defun replace-thing (list thing by &key (test #'eql))
  (labels ((replace-it (tail replaced)
             (if (null tail)
                 (reverse replaced)
               (prog1
                 (if (funcall test (first tail) thing)
                     (replace-it (rest tail) (cons by replaced)) 
                   (replace-it (rest tail) (cons (first tail) replaced)))
                 (format t "~& ~S~%" replaced)))))
    (replace-it list '())))
```

And

```
> (replace-thing '(a b c) 'a 'z)
 (b z)
 (z)
 nil
(z b c)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace occurrences of a string you'll need to pass a list of strings. You passed a list of symbols, not strings. Now you can still replace those symbols with a particular string, but they are not string themselves. The list:

```
'(a b c d e f e)
```

is a list of symbols, not string:

```
 (defun remove-text (str lst)
   (if (atom lst)
       lst
       (if (string-equal (symbol-name (car lst)) str)
           (cons "X" (remove-text str (cdr lst)))
           (cons (car lst) (remove-text str (cdr lst))))))
```

We can pass a string as an argument to check, and then a list of symbol. Our base case will test to see if the list is an atom, at which point we will simply return the list. If not, we will use string-equal to see if the symbol name of the car of the list(which will return the string value of the symbol) is equal to our string. Then we can then cons "X" unto the beginning of the list if that is the case, and then recursively call the function again. If not, we can simply cons the car of the list to the beginning of the list, and recursively call the function again. This function is not tail-recursive, but it recursive, and it does avoid creating a new list structure to store thee result, without destructively altering the structure of the original list. We can test it below:

```
CL-USER> (remove-text "E" '(a b c d e f f e))
(A B C D "X" F F "X")
```